# existing mysql database is lost after initializing database from settings on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I have a really serious and weird problem with MySQL that I could not fix yet.
_
My OS version : Big Sur 11.2.3
MySQL Workbench Version : 8.0.21

I have been working on my local mysql database since long time but interestingly Mysql Workbench could not open the connection today (however I did not make any update or change anything). By the way, I noticed Mysql Workbench consumes around %120 CPU while trying to open the connection and hangs, then I had to cancel the operation in every attempt to open the connection.

I opened Mysql settings from Mac Setting and restarted mysql successfully.
[image]

At that screen I also entered the window below by clicking Initialize Database button right down :
[image]

I entered a password, thought maybe helps to fix my problem and establish the connection

But after entering a password, looks like my existing database is lost (not sure but maybe deleted :( )
[image]
and my DB is not here anymore, just default SYS database is here :
[image]

I don't know if I lost my database but need help to found&reconnect my database

Any help really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: It looks to me that you have two instances of MySQL on your Mac .  Shut the active one off, and start the other one.

Comment: if so, how can I find the existing instances of Mysql on my Mac?